# LED Corn Lights Faulty On/Off or flickering, Mains 230VAC/50HZ

Tags: led, mains

I wonder if someone could help, I have these cheap Chinese corn LED globes that either go ON/OFF randomly after a while or they dim to about 1/3 brilliance or less with faint flicker. they're also not hot to touch, grab or remove.

From new for a couple of hundred hours or so, all was good, then they start to play up. When you first switch them on they may run good for upto half an hour or so.

In the pic there is a diagram of what seems to be the cct for the light. Difference being the capacitor size and voltage. Under the capacitor their are 3 resistors unlike the diagram that only has two. In the light shown I have also re-soldered all the connections as best as I could but the result remains the same.

Any ideas what could be causing them to fail.

[image]

**Update**. I think I figured out what is the cause. Bad Design/Designed to fail/Incompetant design/ Take your pick.

I placed a meter on it and it draws 54ma and the chip runs at around 56 degrees. In the extract from a datasheet I found there are two diagrams 12W and 24W. In their wisdom I would say, O' 12W close enough no need to add another chip. So the chip eventually fails. To add insult to injury thinking they are smart they replaced R1 and R2 with two 68 ohm resistors. O' well nothing can be done about it 3 identical globes 3 failures, 10 bucks down the drain.

I bought the globes from [here](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/B22-LED-Corn-Lamp-7W-12W-15W-20W-25W-27W-30W-35W-AC-220V-5730SMD-Bulb/32429563772.html?spm=2114.search0104.3.260.r48Py9&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_2_10152_10065_10151_10068_10130_10309_10307_10137_10060_10131_10155_10132_10133_10154_10056_10055_10054_10059_9911_100031_10099_10103_10102_10052_10053_10142_10107_10050_10051_10084_10083_10080_10082_10081_10110_10175_10111_10112_10113_10114_10312_10313_10314_10315_10078_10079_10073-9911_10111,searchweb201603_16,ppcSwitch_3&btsid=e880c83d-81b9-42e5-81c1-1235a4679a7b&algo_expid=074179b6-3cea-45b3-9164-f0878e50b9bc-34&algo_pvid=074179b6-3cea-45b3-9164-f0878e50b9bc)

[image]

Comment: That isn't an actual circuit for you light is it?

Comment: It's the only one I could find close enough, chips are the same, resistor values and capacitor differ. Short of reverse engineering the cct board I would say it is.

Comment: You would say "it is"? Which one of the two and do you have a link to a pdf file for the data sheet for the chip - a direct link not via some crappy data sheet vendor please.

Comment: @Andyaka Same as this one? Fast forward to 11:30. He shows them in quite a lot of series connected LED bulbs. https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=NffhdAz9pc4

Comment: Is the capacitor still a capacitor?

Comment: I've added an update above.